# Adding a child to a Container after it is constructed

Tags: flutter

I know this looks a bit weird, but I've boiled down a larger example for this context.

I would like to pass a required child widget and an optional Container widget to a builder function. If there is no container, my child widget is returned.

However, if the container *is* passed to the builder, I want to return the container with the container's child value set to be the child widget parameter.

```dart
Widget myBuilder({
  required Widget child,
  Container? container,
}) {
  if (container == null) return child;
  return // with container's child set to child param?
}

// remember this is contrived for this example -- in my real app, this
// function is in a different package from where container is instantiated
var widget = myBuilder( child: Button(), container: Container() )
```

Comment: from `myBuilder`, you again pass your child to container

Comment: Did you achieve this? I want to do the same thing.